# Finding square pair form the given array in C#

Tags: java, c#

`I have following array {9, 0, 2, -5, 7} and from this array i need to find the the square pairs <2, 7> and <7, 9> where first element must be less than second.
And <-5, 9> and <0, 9> are not square pairs, even though they sum to perfect squares, 
because both members of a square pair have to be greater than 0.

```
        bool ans;
        int[] number = new int[]{9,0,2,-5,7};

        for (int j = 0; j < number.Length; j++)
        {
            if (number[j]<number[j+1])
         ans  =  IsPerfectSquares(number[j]+number[j+1]);
         if(ans) 
        count++;
        }
    }
            public static bool IsPerfectSquares(int input)
        { long SquareRoot = (long)Math.Sqrt(input);
            return ((SquareRoot * SquareRoot) == input);
        } `
```

Comment: what code have to tried so far, post it, then someone can help you

Comment: use foreach and if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# Linq:

```
int[] array = {9, 0, 2, -5, 7};
int len = array.Length;

var pairs =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, len-1)
    where array[i] > 0
    from j in Enumerable.Range(i+1, len-i-1)
    where array[j] > 0
    let sqrt = (int)Math.Sqrt(array[i] + array[j])
    where array[i] + array[j] == sqrt * sqrt
    select new {
        A = Math.Min(array[i], array[j]),
        B = Math.Max(array[i], array[j])
    };
    //or: select new int[] { ... };
```

Results:

```
{ A = 7, B = 9 }
{ A = 2, B = 7 }
```

Java: (also works in C# with slightly different syntax)

```
int[] array = { 9, 0, 2, -5, 7 };
List<int[]> pairs = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; ++i) {
    if (array[i] <= 0) continue;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
        if (array[j] <= 0) continue;
        int sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(array[i] + array[j]);
        if (array[i] + array[j] == sqrt * sqrt)
            pairs.add(new int[] { array[i], array[j] });
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed that first element must be less than second. And I used if condition. But thank you for your answer it really works.

Comment: just change "where array[j] > 0" with "where array[j] > array[i]"

Answer (score 0):

I will let you write the code.

The algorithm is roughly this:

1. Iterate over the array. Remove all elements whose value is less than or equal to zero.
2. Create all possible pairs by using nested loop (two loops). For each pair, take the sum. Let say the sum is S. Take the square root of S. Let say the square root of R. Note that S is an integer (so, it may not exactly the square root of S). Check whether S is a perfect square by checking whether R*R = S.